# Redirect to Firebase Hosting custom domain

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have setup a custom domain with Firebase Hosting (eg. myapp.domain.com).

How can one redirect (or turn off) the default Firebase Hosting URL (eg. myapp.firebaseapp.com) so that the app is only accessible from the custom domain?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You cannot turn off the subdomain. Your app will always be available on `https://myapp.firebaseapp.com` *and* whatever custom domain you've set up.

To redirect people, you can add a `canonical` link to your HTML:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://myapp.domain.com/" />
```

Read more about that in [Specify your canonical](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) on the Google Webmaster Central Blog.

Comment: I've added this to my index.html's <head> and don't get redirected when using the firebase provided url. Is this only for Search Engines? (e.g. I'll be redirected if I clicked it using google?)

Comment: @Jonathan002 you can add JavaScript redirect as mentioned in my answer in addition to adding canonical link.

Answer (score 4):

You could use Firebase Functions.

Free for 125K invocations/month - https://firebase.google.com/pricing

An example using Express middleware:

```js
// functions/index.js

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const url = require('url');

const app = express();

// Allowed domains
let domains = ['localhost:5000', 'example.com'];
// Base URL to redirect
let baseurl = 'https://example.com/';

// Redirect middleware
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (!domains.includes(req.headers['x-forwarded-host'])) {
        return res.status(301).redirect(url.resolve(baseurl, req.path.replace(/^\/+/, "")));
    }
    return next();
});

// Dynamically route static html files
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    return res.sendFile('index.html', { root: './html' });
});

// ...

// 404 middleware
app.use((req, res) => {
    return res.status(404).sendFile('404.html', { root: './html' });
});

// Export redirect function
exports.redirectFunc = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

The exported function name must be added to rewrites in firebase.json e.g.:

```js
{
    "hosting": {
        "public": "public",
        "rewrites": [
          {
            "source": "**",
            "function": "redirectFunc"
          }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this can be achieved without rewrites and just implementing redirect middleware into your http functions server

Answer (score 3):

In addition to specifying canonical link as mentioned in Frank van Puffelen's answer. We can also add front end JavaScript code to do the actual redirect like this without disclosing default url.

```
if (location.hostname.indexOf('custom.url') === -1) {
    location.replace("https://custom.url");
}
```