# Firebase cloud function middleware not redirecting user

Tags: node.js, firebase, url, redirect, google-cloud-functions

I have a firebase hosted website and I am trying to redirect the user from alternative domains in which the site is hosted (i.e. example.com, https://example.com, https://example.firebaseapp.com) to the canonical url, which is https://www.example.com.

However, it seems that the firebase function isn't working, and may not even be running consistently.

I reloaded the website several times after 8pm, however, the only logging of the function was at 7:47. Furthermore, it did not have any of the console.log statements that I expected.

[image]

I deployed my code using firebase deploy so both the functions and the edited firebase.json file should be up-to-date.

Anyone know a) why the function isn't running consistently upon reloading the website and b) why the function isn't working (if I navigate to to our website at the non-canonical URL, I will not be redirected at all).

For reference, the code is as follows (website name has been changed in the question for confidentiality):

functions/index.ts

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const url = require('url');

import type { Request, Response } from 'express';

const app = express();

// Allowed domains
let domains = ['localhost:3000', 'https://exapmle.com', 'https://example.firebaseapp.com'];

// Base URL to redirect to
let baseurl = 'https://www.exampe.com/';

// Redirect middleware
app.use((req: Request, res: Response, next: any) => {
    console.log("testing testing");
    console.log('headers', req.headers['x-forwarded-host']);
    console.log('domains: ', domains);


    if (!domains.includes(req.headers['x-forwarded-host'] as string)) {
        console.log('redirecting')
        return res.status(301).redirect(url.resolve(baseurl, req.path.replace(/^\/+/, "")));
    }
    return next();
});


// Export redirect function
exports.redirectFunc = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

firebase.json

```
{
  ...
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html",
        "function": "redirectFunc"
      }
    ]
  },
  ...
}
```

This is an attempt at implementing the solution found in this question ([Redirect to Firebase Hosting custom domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34212039/redirect-to-firebase-hosting-custom-domain)).

Comment: Have you found your solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no